# sql запрос на сложение на php

Tags: php, sql

```
select sum(ИМЯ_СТОЛБЦА) as summ from ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ;
```

Это sql запрос на сложение  и выводит всё в столбец summ . а как сделать подобный запрос на php только чтобы ещё сложение происходило по определённой записи из другого столбца , то-есть 2 столбца "название" и "число" что-бы складывало значения из столбца "число" по одинаковым записями из столбца "название"? Подскажите кто знает пожалуйста.

Comment: `GROUP BY ИМЯ_СТОЛБЦА` не это ищите?

Comment: group by складывает по сразу все одинаковые ищет и складывает  а мне бы запрос который как по конкретному названию из столбца .

Comment: по конкретному, может просто условие where задать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите, не вполне понял что именно вам нужно, но подозреваю что либо это:

```
SELECT sex, sum(age)
FROM employees
GROUP BY sex;
```

Либо это:

```
SELECT sum(age)
FROM employees
WHERE sex = 'male';
```

Comment: а можете подсказать что тут не так?

Comment: <?php
    $show = $_POST['show'];
    if (isset ($_POST['view'])) { 
        $stmt = $DB_con->query('SELECT FIO_transfer, sum(sum) as summ  FROM transfer where FIO_transfer = '.$show. ' ');
        $stmt ->execute();
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      extract($row);

echo $summ;
}
?>

Comment: запрос складывает все значения , и то когда я ввожу название столбца, а мне нужно чтобы когда я вводил название из ячейки  первого столбца складывались значения из второго столбца

Comment: Ничего не понял. Нарисуйте пример таблички, нарисуйте как должен выглядеть результат запроса. И не постите код в комментариях. читать его тут невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
ИМЯ_СТОЛБЦА_НАЗВАНИЯ as name, sum(ИМЯ_СТОЛБЦА_ЗНАЧЕНИЯ) as summ
from ИМЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ
group by ИМЯ_СТОЛБЦА_НАЗВАНИЯ
```